# not understanding memory management with cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory, cocos2d-iphone

I am allocating a number of ccrepeatforevers under an NSAutoReleasePool.  When I drain the pool I am not getting back the memory I allocated.  Can anyone explain what is wrong with this code and how I can recover the memory I allocated?  In the function "initPlayerAnimations" the variable "a" tracks the memory as shown in the comments in that function.

```
-(void) initPlayerAnimations
{
    if (!playerSpriteDirty) return;
    playerSpriteDirty = false;

    double a = [CCDirector getAvailableMegaBytes];
    // a = 32 megabytes approximately

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool;
    pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

[self wipeAnimations];

    NSString *aString;
    aString = @"YHUMANS";
    [walkAnimations addObject:[self getARepeatForeverFor:aString With:15 AndDelay:mainDelay/15]];
    aString = @"YHUMANE";
    [walkAnimations addObject:[self getARepeatForeverFor:aString With:15 AndDelay:mainDelay/15]];
    aString = @"YHUMANNE";
    [walkAnimations addObject:[self getARepeatForeverFor:aString With:15 AndDelay:mainDelay/15]];
    aString = @"YHUMANN";
    [walkAnimations addObject:[self getARepeatForeverFor:aString With:15 AndDelay:mainDelay/15]];
    aString = @"YHUMANSE";
    [walkAnimations addObject:[self getARepeatForeverFor:aString With:15 AndDelay:mainDelay/15]];

    aString = @"YHUMANSI";
    [idleAnimations addObject:[self getARepeatForeverFor:aString With:25 AndDelay:mainDelay/10]];
    aString = @"YHUMANEI";
    [idleAnimations addObject:[self getARepeatForeverFor:aString With:25 AndDelay:mainDelay/10]];
    aString = @"YHUMANNEI";
    [idleAnimations addObject:[self getARepeatForeverFor:aString With:25 AndDelay:mainDelay/10]];
    aString = @"YHUMANNI";
    [idleAnimations addObject:[self getARepeatForeverFor:aString With:25 AndDelay:mainDelay/10]];
    aString = @"YHUMANSEI";
    [idleAnimations addObject:[self getARepeatForeverFor:aString With:25 AndDelay:mainDelay/10]];

    a = [CCDirector getAvailableMegaBytes];
    // a = 3 megabytes approximately

    [self wipeAnimations];

    [pool drain];

    a = [CCDirector getAvailableMegaBytes];
    // a = 5 megabytes approximately; where is the rest of memory?
}

-(CCAnimation*) animationWithFile2:(NSString*)name
                   frameCount:(int)frameCount
                        delay:(float)delay
{
    NSMutableArray* frames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:frameCount];
    for (int i = 1; i < (1+frameCount); i++)
    {
        NSString* file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i.PNG", name, i];
        CCTexture2D* texture = [self createPlayerSpriteFor:file];
        CGSize texSize = texture.contentSize;
        CGRect texRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, texSize.width, texSize.height);
        CCSpriteFrame* frame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:texture rect:texRect];
        [frames addObject:frame];
    }
    return [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:frames delay:delay];
}

-(CCRepeatForever*) getARepeatForeverFor:(NSString*)aString With:(int)num AndDelay:(double)delay
{
    CCAnimation* anim =  [self animationWithFile2:aString
                                            frameCount:num
                                                 delay:delay];
    CCAnimate* animate = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim];
    CCRepeatForever* repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:animate];

    return repeat;
}

-(void) wipeAnimations
{
    [walkAnimations removeAllObjects];
    [idleAnimations removeAllObjects];
}

-(CCTexture2D*) createPlayerSpriteFor:(NSString*)file
{
    CCSprite *aSprite = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:file];
    aSprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);

    NSArray *anArray = [file componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSString *aString = [anArray objectAtIndex:0];
    CCSprite *bSprite = NULL;

    if (thePlayer.mainHand) {
        aString = [aString stringByAppendingString:@"SWORD.PNG"];
        bSprite = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:aString];
        bSprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
    }

   CCRenderTexture *rt = [[CCRenderTexture alloc]initWithWidth:aSprite.textureRect.size.width height:aSprite.textureRect.size.height pixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_Default];

   [rt begin];

   [aSprite visit];
   if (bSprite)
       [bSprite visit];

   [rt end];

   CCTexture2D *aTex = rt.sprite.texture;
   [aTex setAntiAliasTexParameters];

   [aSprite release];
   [bSprite release];


   return aTex;
}
```

Comment: I guess this is a difficult question.  I am going to try to do my own animation, changing sprite textures via an update function.  That seems like it could work to me.

Comment: Try profiling with instruments memory leaks. Then [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeUnusedTextures] or [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeAllTextures]

Comment: @rraallvv: would that be the equivalent of [[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData]? Because I tried that and it had absolutely no effect.

Comment: purgeCachedData calls sharedTextureCache's removeUnusedTextures, I'd suggest  profiling to find memory leaks

Comment: I've profiled but my live bytes is very stable around 8-10 mb.  There isn't a direct memory leak, but I'm thinking the problem is that my dirty memory increases and then I get terminated by jetsam.  Since live bytes is stable, i am having difficulty understanding why my dirty memory does not clear up in the above code.  In other words, my question is: why is the memory not deallocated?

Comment: Also Instruments' Allocations would tell which methods are allocating the more memory, and try to comment out those calls in your code to see which methods are cousing retentions not being released by purgeCachedData or drainig the NSAutoreleasePool

Comment: How about using ARC and stop worrying about the autorelease bomb?